# Configure MKS Robin WiFi Module on FLSUN Super Racer without Klipper

Tags: firmware, mks, klipper, wi-fi, flsun

I recently purchased an MKS Robin wifi module for my spouse's FLSUN Super Racer after noticing that the printer runs on an MKS Robin Nano V3.1 board. Immediately after installing the chip, I saw it broadcasting a network, so I connected to it and opened the admin in my browser:

[image: screenshot of MKS Robin wifi module admin]

The next few steps seemed pretty straightforward.

1. Update the firmware
2. Setup the wifi connection
3. Connect using the MKS wifi plugin for Cura

I entered the information for my home network and uploaded the firmware. The device quickly updated and gave me a success message before disconnecting the public network it was broadcasting. I then checked my router's device table to see if anything new was connected, but there was nothing. Scratching my head, I troubleshot for about an hour before concluding that I had done something wrong, and now there was nothing I could do, so best to return the chip and get my money back.

I was about to do that this morning and tried to log in on Amazon, but I had no internet connection. So I checked the gateway and opened the admin, and (drum roll) was the admin for the wifi module! What gives?

When I put in the information for my home network, it took that as setup steps for its hotspot, so I had inadvertently logged in thinking it was my home network.

Feeling excited, I decided to try out the MKS Wifi plugin while I was on its network, and the connection was a success!

For a moment.

After queuing up a print, I realized it wasn't working. I get an error message in Cura that reads, "Send file to printer failed."

I found new firmware and a web view for BeePrint [here](https://github.com/xreef/MKS_WIFI_upgrade_with_BeePrint_web_interface/raw/master/firmware_release/). The only thing I have not done at this point is to update the web view. My best guess is that a newer version may not be so bare-bones.

After uploading the new firmware and the web view, it still has not been updated. It's the same boring admin, although I did change the wireless SSID.

I am not sure where to go from here. I watched a [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0GKT0hw_K-4) about setting up the wifi module using Klipper, but completely re-flashing the firmware on the device is not a route that I would like to go. I am worried that I may not have the expertise necessary to pull it off successfully, that even if I do, the printer may not work as well, or worse, I could turn it into a brick with no ability to restore the firmware from backup.

Is there any way to get this wifi module working without those steps? From what I understand, FLSUN does have delta printers with this module installed, but not on the Super Racer. I checked Github for anything in the SR's firmware that might indicate hidden support but found nothing. Is there a way to do this using the factory-installed firmware, or will I have to use something else?